# Quizgame selection doesn't work properly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to create a little quizgame in Javascript and HTML but it doesn't work properly yet. If I select the correct answer and let it validate, i get a wrong output. In my function `showExercise` I tried to set the possible answers always in a different order when it gets invoked. Thus the user is not able to select the right answers by a pattern. I am thankful for any suggetions and corrections.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <title>Quizgame</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Quizgame</h1>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend id="question">Quizgame</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="1" value="1">
        <label for="1">Placeholder</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="2" value="2">
        <label for="2">Placeholder</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="3" value="3">
        <label for="3">Placeholder</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="4" value="4">
        <label for="4">Placeholder</label><br>
        <button onclick="validateInput()">Check</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var exercise = [];
      var index = 0;

      exercise[index] = {
        question:       "Convert this binary number 01000001 to a decimal number:",
        correctAnswer:  "65",
        answer:         [ "127", "33", "42", "65" ]
      };
      index++;
      exercise[index] = {
        question:       "How many combinations can you reach with 3 bits?",
        correctAnswer:  "8",
        answer:         [ "11", "9", "6", "8" ]
      };

      function random( from, to ) 
      {
        min = from > to ? to : from;
        max = to < from ? from : to;
        return( Math.floor( Math.random() * (max - min + 1 ) + min ) );
      }

      function showExercise( val ) 
      {
        document.getElementById( "question" ).innerHTML = exercise[val].question;
        for( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        {
          var index = random( 0, 3 - i );
          console.log(index);
          document.getElementsByTagName( "label" )[i].innerHTML = exercise[val].answer[index];
          exercise[val].answer[index] = exercise[val].answer[3 - i];
        }
      }

      randV = random( 0, index );

      function validateInput()
      {
        var radio = document.getElementsByName( "choice" );
        for( var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++ )
        {
          if( radio[i].checked )
          {
            if( exercise[randV].answer[i] == exercise[randV].correctAnswer[0] )
            {
              alert("Right");
            }
            else
            {
              alert( "Wrong" );
            }
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      showExercise( randV );
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: In the line  ... if( exercise[randV].answer[i] == exercise[randV].correctAnswer[0] ) ... change to ... if( exercise[randV].answer[i] == exercise[randV].correctAnswer )

Comment: the wrong output still persists :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you are assigning possible answers in random order to the labels for the radio buttons but the index mapping that radio button to the answer it represents in your answer array is lost.

To fix this problem I have made a minimal change to your code to store the mapping in the value attribute of each radio button.  Then when the user makes their selection and clicks CHECK the mapping is retrieved for the selected radio button and used to lookup the answer array.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Quizgame</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <h1>Quizgame</h1>
    <form>
      <fieldset>
        <legend id="question">Quizgame</legend>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="1" value="1">
        <label for="1">Placeholder</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="2" value="2">
        <label for="2">Placeholder</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="3" value="3">
        <label for="3">Placeholder</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="choice" id="4" value="4">
        <label for="4">Placeholder</label><br>
        <button onclick="validateInput()">Check</button>
      </fieldset>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      var exercise = [];
      var index = 0;

      exercise[index] = {
        question:       "Convert this binary number 01000001 to a decimal number:",
        correctAnswer:  "65",
        answer:         [ "127", "33", "42", "65" ]
      };
      index++;
      exercise[index] = {
        question:       "How many combinations can you reach with 3 bits?",
        correctAnswer:  "8",
        answer:         [ "11", "9", "6", "8" ]
      };

      function random( from, to ) 
      {
        min = from > to ? to : from;
        max = to < from ? from : to;
        return( Math.floor( Math.random() * (max - min + 1 ) + min ) );
      }

      function showExercise( val ) 
      {
        document.getElementById( "question" ).innerHTML = exercise[val].question;
        for( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
        {
          var index = random( 0, 3 - i );
          console.log(index);
          document.getElementsByTagName( "label" )[i].innerHTML = exercise[val].answer[index];

          //Store the original index to the answer option in the 
          //value attribute of the radio button.
          document.getElementById((i+1).toString()).value = index.toString();
          exercise[val].answer[index] = exercise[val].answer[3 - i];
        }
      }

      randV = random( 0, index );

      function validateInput()
      {
        var radio = document.getElementsByName( "choice" );
        for( var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++ )
        {
          if( radio[i].checked )
          {
            //Retrieve the original index from the radio button
            // and use it to look up the answer array.
            var lOriginalIndex = document.getElementById((i+1).toString()).value;
            if( exercise[randV].answer[lOriginalIndex] == exercise[randV].correctAnswer)
            {

              alert("Right");
            }
            else
            {
              alert( "Wrong" );
            }
            break;
          }
        }
      }

      showExercise( randV );
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```